# Find the general solution and positive integral solutions of 775x -711y =1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Problem :

Find the general solution and  positive integral solutions of 775x -711y =1

My approach :

For the equation ax -by =c , the general solution can be given as :

Let h,k be a solution of ax -by =c, then ah -bk =c.

$ax -by =ah -bk ;$

$a(x-h)=b(y-k); $

$\frac{x-h}{b} = \frac{y-k}{a} =t,$ an integer

$x =h+bt, y =k +at;$ which is the general solution , therefore

We can compare the same with $775x -711y =1$

Let h,k be a solution of $775x -711y =1$ therefore , $775x -711y =1,$

$\Rightarrow 775h -711k =1 $

$\Rightarrow 775h -711 k = 775x -711y $

$\Rightarrow \frac{x-h}{711}=t; \frac{y-k}{775} =t$

Now please suggest how to take this further and get the integral solution of this.

Comment: Using the Euclidean algorithm will give you a solution, since $gcd(775, 711)=1$

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the Euclidean algotithm. Let $a=775,b=711$.

$775=711=64$, so $64=775-711=a-b$.

$711=11*64+7$, so $7=711-11*64=b-11(a-b)=12b-11a$.

$64=9*7+1$, so $1=64-9*7=(a-b)-9(12b-11a)=100a-109b$.

So $x=x_0=100,y=y_0=109$ is one solution of the equation $775x-711y=1$. In parametric form, the general solution is $x=100+711t, y=109+775t,x\in\mathbb R$. If you want $x,y$ to be **integers**, the general solution is $x=100+711t, y=109+775t,x\in\mathbb Z$. If you want $x,y$ to be **positive integers**, you have to satisfy the inequalities $100+711t\gt0$ and $109+775t\gt0$, i.e., $t=0,1,2,3,\dots$. The resulting solutions are $(100,109),(811,884),(1522,1659),(2233,2434),\dots$.